# The HTML drag element shadow starts from top of the screen

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I am using the HTML Drag Drop API for performing a drag event. The API it seems is in-consistent and presents strange results.
How to solve this behavior. When you drag the Element, the show starts from top of the screen.
[image]

there is no onDrag function only the onDragStart function

```
onDragStart={(e)=>{
                if(projectContext.board.cardDragging){
                    return false;
                }
                projectContext.update('board',{...projectContext.board,'cardDragging':{...card,user:select('vibebp').getUser()} });
            }}
```

how can I prevent this behaviour by the HTML dragDrop API.

Comment: Is there not more code you can provide? I would guess somehow the dragged-item is getting top-of-parent coordinates initially, and is quickly updating position once you start moving the mouse. So you need to scrutinize your dragging setup as well as potentially any CSS interrupting it. Anyhow there _is_ a `.drag` listener that fires every few 100 milliseconds; that's the "onDrag" you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/drag_event. Notice there is no `onDragStart` natively; so, are you using a 3rd-party script?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not exactly but I solved the issue by removing the onDrag function. I am using reactJS and I assumed that the time react re-renders and the HTML animation start is mismatched here. So I removed the onDrag function and things seem to have resolved for now.